# How to get all string which are after a specific string into an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have a string like this,

```
$string = "You have to know [#4], [#2] and [#5] too";
```

I want to get all the values which are after the string of "[#" into an array.

I am using a method, and this is working. But if there is a plain text and there is no "[]" then it gives error.

I am using this method,

```
$search_string = "[";
    $count = 0;
    $ids = array();

    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++) {
        $position = strpos($string, $search_string , $count);
        if ($position == $count) {
            $ids[] = $string[$position + 2];
        }
        $count++;
    }
```

Is there any way to make it appropriate?

My goal is I want to get the numbers into $ids array which are after the string of "[#", and if there is no brace then count($ids) will be 0

Comment: Use reqular expression.

Comment: Please give an answer about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're looking for specific patterns in some target string, one common approach is to employ [**preg_match_all()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) function. For example:

```
$string = "You have to know [#4], [#2] and [#5] too";
$ids = [];
preg_match_all('/\\[#(\d+)[^]]*]/', $string, $ids);

print_r($ids[1]);
```

In this case, pattern `/\[#\d+([^]]*)]/` is used; it matches all the sequences that start with `[#`, followed by at least one digit, followed by any number of non-`]` character, followed by `]`. As capturing group is used, the values you're looking for are stored in `$ids[1]`.

Note that for strings without any target sequences there'll be no matches, hence `$ids[1]` will be an empty array - which looks to be what you want.

Also note that if you only want to count the number of matches, you don't even need to supply `$ids` as argument of `preg_match_all` - just use its return value:

```
$string = "You have to know [#4], [#2] and [#5] too";
var_dump( preg_match_all('/\\[#([^]]+)]/', $string) ); // int(3)
```

Comment: Is there any solution if I have like this, "You have to know @[#4 some name], @[#2 another name] and @[#5 one another name] too"; Then how to get the value after "[#"

Comment: Just augment the pattern accordingly - `/\[#([^]]+)]/`. Will update the answer.

Comment: It gives the whole string like "4 another name". But I just want 4. Any solution?

Comment: Hello @raina77ow, Please provide an answer.

Comment: Updated the answer once more.

Answer (score 0):

```
$re = '/\[#(?P<digit>\d+)]/';
$str = 'You have to know [#4], [#2] and [#5] too';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

var_dump($matches['digit']);
```